# Doubt from Spivak's proof of Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> ***2-11 Theorem (Inverse Function Theorem)***. *Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuously differentiable in an open set containing $a$, and det $f'(a)\neq 0$. Then there is an open set $V$ containing $a$ and an open set $W$ containing $f(a)$ such that $f:V\to W$ has a continuous inverse $f^{-1}:W\to V$ which is differentiable and for all $y\in W$ satisfies $$(f^{-1})'(y) = [f'(f^{-1}(y))]^{-1}$$*
>   ***Proof.*** Let $\lambda$ be the linear transformation $Df(a)$. Then $\lambda$ is non-singular, since det $f'(a)\neq 0$. Now $D(\lambda^{-1}\circ f)(a) = D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a))\circ Df(a) = \lambda^{-1}\circ Df(a)$ is the identity linear transformation.

why is $D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a))\circ Df(a) = \lambda^{-1}\circ Df(a)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the derivative of a linear transformation $L : V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is the linear transformation itself. In your case, $L$ is $\lambda^{-1}$. This may be a little counterintuitive but it follows directly from the definition:

The derivative of $L$ at $x \in V$, **if you can find it**, is *some* linear transformation $DL_x : V \to W$ that must satisfy:
$$
\lim_{h \to \overrightarrow{\mathbf{0}}}\Big| \frac{L(x + h) - L(x) - DL_x(h)}{h} \Big| = 0
$$ But $L$ is linear so $L(x + h) - L(x) = L(x) + L(h) - L(x) = L(h)$. So in fact you are just looking for a linear transformation $DL_x$ such that
$$
\lim_{h \to \overrightarrow{\mathbf{0}}}\Big| \frac{L(h) - DL_x(h)}{h} \Big| = 0
$$ Well, $L$ itself is a linear transformation. So what if you do the obvious thing and let $DL_x$ equal $L$? Then the condition above is indeed satisfied because the numerator becomes just $\overrightarrow{\mathbf{0}}$. So defining $DL_x = L$ works and we have discovered that the derivative $DL_x$ of a linear transformation $L$, at any arbitrary point $x$, is $L$ itself.

Comment: It's not so counterintuitive if you think of the derivative of a function as its linearisation at a point.
If you linearise a linear function, well... you are finished before you started!

Comment: This all depends on what is meant by "counterintuitive".  It certainly isn't mathematically counterintuitive.  But it may well be psychologically counterintuitive because encountering this theory for the first time can be overwhelming and we expect great complexity.  We don't typically expect simple patterns here like a linear function being its own derivative.